# WPF Application Getting Stuck on Window Resize

Tags: c#, wpf

My team develops WPF application with .NET Framework 4.6.1.
We are facing issue in which in case user is resizing the application window or sub windows while Main thread is busy with UI updates then the all application is getting stuck/freeze and only after doing some manipulations like opening Task Manager it is getting released.
I read over different forums that this issue may happen due to WPF issue with calculating the available space when using "*" for auto width/height in UI controls and in our applications we using it a lot.
Does this issue in known?
If yes, was it handled in recent .NET Framework versions?

Comment: We need to see code that shows the problem.

Comment: XamlAnimatedGif WPF libarary has similar issue, if someone comes here trying to solve more generic issue.
https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif/issues/189

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the culprit is a GUI change happening which is not being expressed on the main GUI thread. Note that property changes (which are most likely tied to `INotifyPropertyChange`) even as integers could cause a crash/exception if not performed on the gui thread.

---

When in doubt, drop into the gui thread to do all visual changes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this to safely perform an action which involves any of the properties of the VM.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation"></param>
    public static void SafeOperationToGuiThread(Action operation)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(operation);
    }
```

usage

```
SafeOperationToGuiThread(() => { IsOperationOnGoing = true; HasLoginFailure = false; });
```

---

Otherwise you will need to *divide an conquer* by removing all controls/ operations which your screen change affects. When the app doesn't crash, re-add controls/operations until the crash happens.